# Resuming from suspend temporarily 'fixes' sound on 14.04, how can I mimic the resume?

Tags: sound, suspend

Sound stops working frequently on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop.

I have tried the myriad fixes to no avail.

However, I noticed that when I close my laptop, let it suspend and open it up again the sound works.

So, is there a way of replicating the relevant portion of whatever happens without actually sleeping & waking?

**Note**: The myriad of fixes mentioned above includes the procedures in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure.

Comment: This is still an issue.

Comment: Still an issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that pulseaudio stops running for some reason  , copy and run  this command in a terminal:
`killall -9 pulseaudio`
Pulseaudio will be stopped then automatically relaunched , hopefully sound will be ok.

If not, try:
`sudo alsa force-reload`
which will restart Alsa audio layer.

Comment: edited answer to add :   sudo alsa force-reload

Comment: Thanks again, this didn't work (I tried all the stuff in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure).